# External monitor not going to sleep (MATE 15.04)

Tags: multiple-monitors, 15.04, suspend, external-monitor, mate

System : Ubuntu MATE 15.04

Machine : [Toshiba Radius P55W-C5200](http://www.toshiba.com/us/computers/laptops/satellite/Radius15/P55W-C5200)

External monitor : Lenovo 23" IPS LED HD

```
uname -a

3.19.0-25-generic #26-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 24 21:16:27 UTC 2015 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
```

The option in Power management:

"Put display to sleep when inactive for" x minutes

does not turn off the monitor

[EDIT]

This seems to be a MATE only issue, as explained here:

[External monitor not going to sleep](https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/external-monitor-not-going-to-sleep/1908)

The behaviour (monitor not sleeping) only happens when the laptop lid is closed. Keeping the laptop lid open the external monitor does go to sleep.